# Retrofit class file for retrofit2.Retrofit not found

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2

I have the following dependencies in my application:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha02'
implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'
implementation 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.7.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.7.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.3'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.4.0'
```

I initially had different versions of the retrofit libraries which were causing errors. [Refrofit dependency issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54905331/retrofit2adapter-rxjava-certificate-issue/54905511#54905511) I have resolved that issue. However, now on the compilation, I get the following error:

***error: cannot access Retrofit*
*class file for retrofit2.Retrofit not found***

The method that results in this error is the getClient method. 
As far as I know, this is the right way to initialise

```
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
private static int REQUEST_TIMEOUT = 60;
private static OkHttpClient okHttpClient;


public static Retrofit getClient(Context context)
{

    if (okHttpClient == null)
        initOkHttp(context);

    if (retrofit == null)
    {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(CaselotREST.CASELOT_BASEURL)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

Comment: Ever get this figured out? Still happens to me.

Answer (score 2):

Probably a problem in **gradle.build**. A possible variant of why this is happening to you is to use an instance of Retrofit in another module. You need to add dependencies for Retrofit to your application module or wherever you need dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.
for me dependencies block was out of android block in build.gradle for app.
solution: move dependencies block into android{ } block.

android{
.
.
.

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.7.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.7.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

}